# Better way to apply function to every combination of two columns in Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, function, pandas, apply

I want to implement a something just like `DataFrame.corr()` which can apply a function to pairwise columns.
Eg.
I have a function:

```
def func(x, y):
    pass
```

I want to apply `func` to every combination of two columns in `a_pd`(type of `Pandas.DataFrame`). I have figured out a way by create a new function `wap_func` to wrap `func`:

```
def wap_func(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(x)):
            func(x[i], x[j])

res = a_pd.apply(wap_func, axis=1)
```

Although the question seems to be solved, but it isn't convenient. If it could be done like `a_pd.corr()`, it could be better.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) module?

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,5,7]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(df)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  5  7
```

Define your function slightly differently so that you can use apply more seamlessly

```py
def func(xy):
    x, y = xy
    return x+y
```

Use the `itertools.combinations` module to get all combinations of the columns that you wish, go through each of the combinations in turn, and apply the function earlier defined

```py
for combi in combinations(df.columns, 2):
    df['_'.join([i for i in combi])] = df[[i for i in combi]].apply(func, axis=1, result_type='expand').transpose().values

print(df)

   A  B  C  A_B  A_C  B_C
0  1  2  3    3    4    5
1  2  3  4    5    6    7
2  3  5  7    8   10   12
```

Comment: Sorry! Provided an example now :) I did want to just comment as I had thought the comment would be enough for the OP but I'm new here and don't have that privilege yet

Comment: Turned it into an answer. Well done. Sorry that I cannot upvote for lack of technical knowledge.